# Div hidden underneath containing div scrollbar with overflow: scroll set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some content that is wrapped by a div that has overflow set to scroll. Inside that div I have a rows of bootstrap drop down buttons. When you get to the drop down button closest to the bottom edge of the div the dropdown area is hidden by the div scroll bar.

[image: Dropdown Div hidden underneath container div scrollbar]

Is there a way to have that dropdown show above the scrollbar? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I've added a very simple Fiddle to show what is currently happening

**CSS:**

```
div.container
{
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}

table#fiddleTable th
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gnex/8GAc3/

Comment: Try higher `z-index` on dropdown content. Also try set `overflow-y: visible;`.

Comment: Can you make a quick fiddle?

Comment: I updated the Question with a link to JS Fiddle. Thanks

Comment: @Gnex how you solved your problem? I'm not working with Bootstrap but I have the same problem (the content of my dropdown menu inside my table cells are hidden by a div scrollbar). I saw Skelly response but I think isn't a good solution and don't solve my problem

Comment: @Ninita Denk below gave a response that I'm going to try and use in my solution. I will update this question once I've tested it.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve the same thing, this works for me:

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").click (e) ->
menu = $(this).next(".dropdown-menu")
menuPositionY = e.clientY + menu.height() + 180
#check if dropdown exceeds the Y coordinate of viewport
if $(window).height() < menuPositionY
  menu.css
    top: "auto"
    bottom: "100%"
else
  menu.css
    bottom: "auto"
    top: "100%"
```

Check the jsfiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/8GAc3/6/

Comment: I'm going to try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to re-position the dropdown menu..

```
.dropdown-menu{
    left:40px;
    top:-10px;
}
```

## [Bootply](http://bootply.com/96206)

Comment: I saw your Bootply response. Will this also work with BootStrap 2?